# Remove shortcut for paste and match style

Tags: keyboard, shortcut

Latest OSX update (10.13.3 (17D47)) added a shortcut cmd-shift-V for Edit -> Paste and Match Style globally. This interferes with my selected shortcut for ClipMenu paste https://github.com/naotaka/ClipMenu/issues/35

How do I remove a global shortcut like that?

Update:
Seems like the origin of my question is solved. Seems it was ClipMenu who's shortcut just stopped working after last OSX update. Changed it for Clipy which seems to be an alive fork that is working still. So the shortcut set in the app seems to override any system default.

However, I still don't understand how to actually remove a global OSX shortcut like that one which I would like to do. So I leave the question unanswered.

Answer (score 2):

Go to `App Shortcuts` defined in `System Preferences → Keyboard → Shortcuts → App Shortcuts` and override the default shortcut.

[image]

Comment: It just doesn't work for me though. Whatever I put there, the cmd-shift-v is still there on all apps for "Paste and Match Style". I also would want to bind nothing to that command, but I'd be ok with something obscure like cmd-option-ctrl-shift-q or something.

Comment: I do not understand how that could be possible... Whatever you put in App Shortcuts overrides standard things globally. Suppose everything was done exactly as on the picture including All Applications, Menu Title text and some other shortcut?